Why The Primary Reference Is Copied to Bin
I have a .net SDK Style project, and it adds a PackageReference for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager with version 4.7.0, and I used MSBuild to build this project, in the build log I see a place referring to this package as below:

Primary reference "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager,
Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
(TaskId:858)
Resolved file path is "C:.tools.nuget\packages\system.configuration.configurationmanager\4.7.0\ref\net461\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll".
(TaskId:858)
Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:858)
This reference is not "CopyLocal" because at least one source item had "Private" set to "false" and no source items had "Private"
set to "true". (TaskId:858)

It seems telling that the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll is not included in the build output, but I still see this assembly is included in the bin folder. I wonder what does "is not CopyLocal" exactly mean? Does it mean CopyLocal=false for this item, so it will not be copied to the output. But I can see this assembly is presented in the output bin folder. Does anyone has any idea on this?
